# What are gossip_store flags and why do I get the messages about dying channels?

Tags: core-lightning, channels, logging, ln-gossip

I have a couple of private channels in my Core Lightning node that runs over Tor.
Today it logged:

```
lightningd: Server started with public key ***************************, alias ******** (color #******) and lightningd v24.02
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @24968004 for 256 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @26397145 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @26397295 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @26475428 for 256 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @30246804 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @30246954 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.902Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @23264743 for 256 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.902Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @30822167 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:53.902Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @23265825 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:59.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @8422867 for 256 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:59.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @36069597 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:59.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @36291961 for 258 already set!
2024-03-23T05:51:59.527Z **BROKEN** gossipd: gossip_store flag-2048 @8426511 for 257 already set!
2024-03-23T05:52:44.590Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 834847x2282x1 already deleted?
2024-03-23T05:52:44.591Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 800108x1316x1 already deleted?
2024-03-23T05:52:44.591Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 834847x2282x1 already deleted?
2024-03-23T05:52:44.591Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 800108x1316x1 already deleted?
2024-03-23T06:01:16.091Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 835269x2049x0 already deleted?
2024-03-23T06:01:16.091Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 835269x2049x0 already deleted?
2024-03-23T06:01:47.171Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 775341x2972x0 already deleted?
2024-03-23T06:02:18.349Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 775341x2972x0 already deleted?
2024-03-23T06:02:51.095Z **BROKEN** gossipd: Dying channel 835547x1728x1 already deleted?
```

When I run `listpeerchannels` all is fine, the channels are reconnected and ready to use.
Bitcoin Core logs:

```
2024-03-23T16:41:43Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000000ef4c3ebfba280fe055aabe0ffb1e5777c5fe894f1512 height=835944 version=0x20400000 log2_work=94.813600 tx=979724424 date='2024-03-23T16:41:30Z' progress=1.000000 cache=51.5MiB(429836txo)
2024-03-23T16:47:05Z Saw new header hash=00000000000000000002a6e35f0c8c6f29adb034df04cb13b26ae9b353670102 height=835945
2024-03-23T16:47:05Z [net] Saw new cmpctblock header hash=00000000000000000002a6e35f0c8c6f29adb034df04cb13b26ae9b353670102 peer=0
2024-03-23T16:47:11Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000002a6e35f0c8c6f29adb034df04cb13b26ae9b353670102 height=835945 version=0x25ce6000 log2_work=94.813615 tx=979726897 date='2024-03-23T16:46:40Z' progress=1.000000 cache=52.0MiB(434993txo)
2024-03-23T16:51:28Z Flushed fee estimates to fee_estimates.dat
```

What is happening here? Are the message from `gossipd` about other channels than the ones I have?